# Hide extension of php files and hide index.php with htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This has been asked a thousand times, but not exactly how I want it. I have tried combining different solutions, but my .htaccess doesn't seem to do what it is supposed to.

```
# Not sure what this does?
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]

# Redirect index in any directory to root of that directory
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z](3,9)\ /([^/]+/)*index\.[^\ ]*\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*)index(\.[a-z0-9]+)?$ http://www.example.com/$1? [R=301,L]
```

Now my pages correctly change from `domain.com/page1.php` to `domain.com/page1`, however something goes wrong with `domain.com/index.php`.

I am testing this locally and when going to `localhost/project` everything works fine (the `index.php` opens, but you don't see that in the url) but when you explicitly navigate to `localhost/project/index.php` you are returned to the very root, i.e. `localhost` (which hen returns to `http://localhost/xampp/splash.php`). Of course, this is not what I want. I want `localhost/project/index.php` to return to `localhost/project/´.

An additional question, though: how do rewrite rules influence search engines. Will the pages (ie contact.php, about-us.php and so on) still be indexed?

*Extra +1 and kudos for he or she who gives a detailed breakdown of what each line/rule in the htaccess in their answer does. I am still learning .htaccess, so every detail is important and relevant to me!*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lot of comments in this code in question seem to be mine :)

Anyway you can use this code to fix your issue:

```
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /project/

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+project/+(.*?/)?(?:index)?(.*?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1%2 [R=302,L,NE]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/project/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

**Update:** For using in `DocumentRoot`:

```
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?/)?(?:index)?(.*?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1%2 [R=302,L,NE]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but this doesn't work at all. `contact.php` correctly rewrites to `contact`, but I then get a 404 error. `Index.php` still refers to localhost itself and not to its base folder.

Comment: No, it's inside `http://localhost/project/.htaccess`, all the other .php files are also in `http://localhost/project`.

Comment: `index.php` still redirects to `localhost/`, the other links do work!

Comment: Maybe it's got something to do with XAMPP?

Comment: Still the same behaviour. index.php redirects to localhost.

Comment: It was a caching problem indeed. I'm sorry for the trouble! It works fine now. If this project goes live, and I place this on its own domain (so not inside a /project/), will I have to change something to that code?

Comment: Thanks again. Can't test that last code, but when the project goes live I'll let you know!

Comment: Sure, feel free to leave a comment here and I will respond.